# I receive the message "No module named tensorflow" in every attempt to install tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed Python 3.6.3 on Windows with Anaconda packages. I tried several times to install tensorflow by creating new environments and following the ways people mentioned in this forum. I always receive the message "No module named tensorflow". I was wondering if the tensorflow is developed for this version of Python.

Comment: What are the exact commands you typed to install tensorflow?

Comment: Tensorflow windows distributions support pip or conda on python 3.6 ([since 1.2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md)), you don't have to do a manual install. [Tensorflow 1.5 is available on conda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow) for windows. You can use `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow` to install it via anaconda. [Tensorflow 1.8 is also available via pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow), you can use `pip install tensorflow` to install via pip.

Comment: Great! Thank you, it works well now.